# iOS App and persistent login (Apparently an phone-specific AND app-specific issue)

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, ios, authentication, cookies

I'm having a really strange problem. I've written an iOS/Rails app in which users have accounts, and need to log in to perform all kinds of actions within the app.

When the app launches, the app detects whether the user's username and password have been stored. If not, it prompts for login credentials. Anyway, logging in seems to be working perfectly, and the server sends back the appropriate response.

However, when I try to do anything else in the app that requires being logged in, I get an error from the server saying I don't have the login credentials. I didn't think I had to do anything special with the cookies (i.e. I thought they were stored automatically), but maybe I'm wrong?

If some code samples would help, let me know what snippets you'd like to see and I'll post them, but I feel like this is more of a conceptual misunderstanding on my part than anything else.

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: I tested the app on my friend's phone, and it works fine. It's only my phone which is having trouble with the app. I looked for any settings involving cookies, but because all the apps are sandboxed, changing settings with cookies in Safari, for example, won't help. I'm pulling my hair out with this issue. I've restarted my phone, deleted and reinstalled the app, and tried changing some of the code, without any success. The Facebook app works as expected, so I assume cookies are being stored in Facebook's sandbox. Only my app seems to be having this problem, but it was working yesterday. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

After you login you need to store the cookie which is returned. It will then be sent with every request afterwards.

Take alook at theses q's:

[Objective-C Asynchronous Web Request with Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704985/objective-c-asynchronous-web-request-with-cookies)

[Managing HTTP Cookies on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053568/managing-http-cookies-on-iphone)

[iPhone NSData/NSUrl with cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005521/iphone-nsdata-nsurl-with-cookie)

Comment: Can you try logging out if the cookies are being sent on your requests? How is it behaving in the simulator?